# Multiple markers at this Access of undefined property completeHandler. -uLdr1 Access of undefined property uLdr1

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I need to load my XML file.
But i am unable to figure out why uLdr1 variable not working.

My code that i have right now is below:

```
public var url1:String="itemsDPI.xml";
            public var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest(url1);
            public var uLdr1:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
            uLdr1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler);
            uLdr1.load(req);


public function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
                var ldr:URLLoader = event.currentTarget as URLLoader;
                var xmlDP:XML = new XML(ldr.data);

            }
```

Comment: Looks good, maybe you set invalid path, handle IOErrorEvent.

Comment: thanks... but how to set path ?

Comment: thanks Kulikovsky....code is working now